# How to use this variable to get the id of input in typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead for the first time and it should be an easy question for many of u. I have multiple input element for which i am using typeahead. All those elements have same class.

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="element_1" >
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="element_2" >
```

When typeahead is active on any element i need to determine it's id. This is what I am trying.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'items',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source:populateItems()
});


var populateItems=function(){
    return function findMatches(inp, cb) {
    console.log("id: "+$(this).id);   //this is where i need to find the id
    jQuery.get("auto_suggestion.php",function(data){
        // some work here ..
        cb(res);
    });
  };
};
```

I tried to see their examples and other sources on web but didn't find much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access element from data source function. `this` points to `Dataset` object, and there is no reference to input element. However you can initialize typeahead in `each` loop, so you can access current input element:

```
$('.typeahead').each(function() {
    $(this).typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'items',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: populateItems(this.id)
    })
});


function populateItems (id) {
    return function findMatches(inp, cb) {
        console.log("id: " + id);
        // ...
    };
};
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. 
OK so there is one new problem, what should be the syntax if i add some of the input element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

... this uses jQuery, but get's the Id attribute using a quick, simple method that I use all the time.

Comment: not working, i think $(this) refers to something else within findMatches() function.